# Exporting Ant design table to pdf format

Tags: reactjs, antd

recently I have been creating antd table component. I have a requirement that i need to convert the ant-d table to pdf format. I went through the antd documentation but could not find any such feature converting andtd table to pdf format. So, all I am asking is, whether there is any library that can be used to convert antd table to pdf or is there any other workaround for converting react table component to pdf format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no antd solution for this, but you can use other libraries to create pdf on client side, like [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/) or [kendo pdf generator](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/pdfprocessing/get-started/).

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help you get an idea, I'm using vue js and I'm able to convert antd table to pdf,
you just need to declare an id in the particular antd table you want to export and pass that id through the props to the pdf.js file or whatever.

```
<a-row :gutter="[15, 15]" class="mt-20">
        <a-col :span="24">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <a-table
                    bordered
                    :columns="columns"
                    :row-key="(record) => record.xid"
                    :data-source="table.data"
                    :pagination="table.pagination"
                    :loading="table.loading"
                    @change="handleTableChange"
                    id="users-reports-table"
                >
```

here the id is "users-reports-table" and then passing that id through props to

exportpdf.vue:

```
<template>
    <a-col :span="24">
        <a-button type="primary" @click="downloadPdf" :loading="loading">
            <FilePdfOutlined />
            {{ $t("common.pdf") }}
        </a-button>
    </a-col>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { FilePdfOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons-vue";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";

export default {
    props: {
        tableName: {
            type: String,
            default: "",
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: "",
        },
    },
    components: {
        FilePdfOutlined,
    },
    setup(props) {
        const loading = ref(false);

        const downloadPdf = () => {
    loading.value = true;

    var pdf = new jsPDF();
        
            pdf.text(props.title, 14, 9);
            pdf.autoTable({ html: `#${props.tableName} table` });
            pdf.save(`${props.tableName}.pdf`);
        }

    

    loading.value = false;
    
};

        return {
            downloadPdf,
            loading,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```